# Replacing NOT IN with NOT EXISTS and an OUTER JOIN in Oracle Database 12c

Tags: oracle, outer-join, not-exists

I understand that the performance of our queries is improved when we use EXISTS and NOT EXISTS in the place of IN and NOT IN, however, is performance improved further when we replace NOT IN with an OUTER JOIN as opposed to NOT EXISTS?

For example, the following query selects all models from a PRODUCT table that are not in another table called PC. For the record, no model values in the PRODUCT or PC tables are null:

```
select model
from product
where not exists(
select * 
from pc
where product.model = pc.model);
```

The following OUTER JOIN will display the same results:

```
select product.model
from product left join pc
on pc.model = product.model
where pc.model is null;
```

Seeing as these both return the same values, which option should we use to better improve the performance of our queries?

Comment: The two should be the same.  Oracle has a good optimizer and both of these are ways of expression an semi anti join.

Comment: "I understand that the performance of our queries is improved when we use EXISTS and NOT EXISTS in the place of IN and NOT IN". In some cases. In other cases IN or NOT IN perform better. Performance depends on the relative size of the driving query and the subquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query plan will tell you. It will depend on the data and tables. In the case of OUTER JOIN and NOT EXISTS they are the same.

However to your opening sentence, NOT IN and NOT EXISTS are not the same if NULL is accepted on model. In this case you say model cannot be null so you might find they all have the same plan anyway. However when making this assumption, the database must be told there cannot be nulls (using NOT NULL) as opposed to there simply not being any.  If you don't it will make different plans for each query which may result in different performance depending on your actual data.  This is generally true and particularly true for ORACLE which does not index NULLs.

Check out EXPLAIN PLAN

Comment: The queries result in the same result set, regardless of whether the columns are `NULL`.  They are likely to have the same execution plan.  Hence, they are very likely to be exactly equivalent.

Comment: Yes agreed that without nulls in the data the results will be the same regardless.  However if there were nulls they would be different results.  The DB needs to know that NULL is not an option otherwise the EXISTS and IN will not generate the same plan even though we know the result will be the same.

Comment: `NOT EXISTS` and `LEFT JOIN`/`WHERE IS NULL` are exactly the same.  You may be confusing this with `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS`, where `NULL` handling is different.

Comment: Yes - I am referring to NOT IN/EXISTS.  I'll update for clarity.